# Dynamic Sql statement change by variable in method Up

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-migrations, npgsql

I would like to insert values into PostgreSql table using code first migration.
My code so far:

```
public override void Up()
{
    var test = "TestValue";
    Sql(@"Insert into dbo.""Company"" (""Id"", ""Name"") values ('2', test)");
}
```

This is sample code. What I am trying to achieve is insert precomputed value to `Name` column. The above code will fail with the message `there is no column named test` but my intention is to substitute the value of `test`. Please help me with the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities either using [string concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-concatenate-multiple-strings) or the [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). If you need formatted output e.g. number of decimals in a number etc. then you should use [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

[String concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-concatenate-multiple-strings):

```
var test = "TestValue";
string sqlString = @"Insert into dbo.""Company"" (""Id"", ""Name"") values ('2', '" + test + @"')";
Sql(sqlString);
```

[String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var test = "TestValue";
string sqlString = string.Format(@"Insert into dbo.""Company"" (""Id"", ""Name"") values ('2', '{0}')", test);
Sql(sqlString);
```

Your `sqlString` will contain:
`Insert into dbo."Company" ("Id", "Name") values ('2', 'TestValue')` after it.

Comment: This works for me with single quotes around {0} as '{0}'. Thanks!

Comment: @hima: Thank you I've added it and extend my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader;
            var test = "Test";
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert INTO yourTableName (Id,Name) VLAUES ('2' ," + test + ")"; 
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added an explanation to why this answers the question.